# CDO Open failed on *.nc no such file or directory

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate

I am new with CDO, and wanted to use it to merge several netcdf files on the time variable with

```
cdo mergetime pr_Amon_IITM-ESM_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_199001-199912.nc pr_Amon_IITM-ESM_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_201001-201412.nc output.nc
```

I just installed CDO on Mac following the instructions given here: https://thiagodossantos.com/post/1-mac-science-software/.
I have Version 1.9.9 and it seems to work fine, however it can't open any .nc file I have tried so far.

This is the error message I got:

```
cdo    mergetime: Open failed on >pr_Amon_IITM-ESM_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_199001-199912.nc<
              No such file or directory
```

This is the Version I am using:

Climate Data Operators version 1.9.9 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)

System: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0

CXX Compiler: /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-10 -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk -arch x86_64  -pthread
CXX version : g++-mp-10 (MacPorts gcc10 10.2.0_4) 10.2.0

C Compiler: /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-10 -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk -arch x86_64  -pthread -pthread

C version : gcc-mp-10 (MacPorts gcc10 10.2.0_4) 10.2.0

F77 Compiler: gfortran -pipe -Os -m64

F77 version : GNU Fortran (MacPorts gcc10 10.2.0_4) 10.2.0

Features: 8GB 4threads C++14 Fortran PTHREADS HDF5 NC4/HDF5 OPeNDAP SZ UDUNITS2 PROJ CURL FFTW3 SSE3

Libraries: HDF5/1.12.0 proj/5.2.0 curl/7.74.0

Filetypes: srv ext ieg grb1 grb2 nc1 nc2 nc4 nc4c nc5
CDI library version : 1.9.9
ecCodes library version : 2.19.1
NetCDF library version : 4.7.4 of Jan 28 2021 10:09:27 $
hdf5 library version : 1.12.0
exse library version : 1.4.1
FILE library version : 1.9.1

I've also tried to reinstall it, but it didn't help. Any help is much appreciated!

P.S: I am also new with stack overflow, so please excuse me if I didn't ask the question correctly.

Comment: Can you please add the CDO call you have used and what error was produced?

Comment: yes of course, I edited my question

Comment: Are you sure the file exists in current directory?

Comment: Yes I am, I tried it with several files and it was always the same error message.

Comment: It worked when I moved it out of the iCloud Drive and into my users folder.

Comment: Does that not mean the file is not actually in the folder, so there is no way for CDO to find it?

Comment: I am not sure, because I could access it with other programs. But maybe you are right. Anyways, the problem is solved :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar problem, and I fixed it by closing that `.nc` by calling `nc_close("file")-file` after performing my calculations.